# while loop illegal break

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop, break

Ok I keep getting illegal break in my code while running it in chrome.

```
//village
var village = function () {
    document.write("<p>You come to a small village with a Smiths shop, a bakery, a guards Tower, and a bank. If you follow thst path some more you'll wind up going into the forrest.</p>")
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)
    while (choice != "bakery" || "tower" || "bank" || "forrest" || "smith") {
        var choice = prompt("bakery,tower,smith,bank,forrest")
        if (choice = "bakery") {

            villageBakery(); // its this line getting flagged, not even the bellow it. only this line.

            break;
        } else if ("tower") {
            document.write("<p>You walk up and knock on the door. No one came.</p>")
        } else if ("smith") {
            villageSmith()
            break
        } else if ("bank") {
            villageBank()
            break
        } else if (choice == "forrest") {
            forrest()
            break
        } else {
            document.write("<p>Please type the choices as shown</p>");
            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)
        };
    };
};
```

I've tried googling the problem but I keep coming up short. I have my other functions set up the same way but its only saying this one is busted.

Comment: try `if(choice == "bakery"){`; you need to compare instead of assign.

Comment: Your `while` condition comparison is wrong; `||` doesn't work that way in JavaScript. All of your `if` comparisons that just mention a string (`if ("bank")`) are wrong; they might as well read `if (true)`. And, as noted above, it should be `if (choice == "bakery")`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the conditions , your while conditions are against the if conditions which means whatever inside the if wont runt, you can do something like this:

> while (choice === "bakery" || choice ==="tower" || choice ==="bank" ||
> choice ==="forrest" ||"choice ===smith") {
>
> ```
>     var choice = prompt("bakery,tower,smith,bank,forrest")
>     if (choice === "bakery") {
>
>         villageBakery(); // its this line getting flagged, not even the bellow it. only this line.
>
>         break;
>     } else if (choice ==="tower") {
> ```

hope this can help

Answer (score -1):

Put semicolons behind your brake statements:
      `break;`

Comment: That will not change anything; the language will assume those semicolons are there.